# Configure email alias

Tags: linux, email

I know you can add the alias of an ID in email server, but is that alias configurable too?

Let's say I have an ID:

```
original@domain.com with
Pass: original pass
```

I created an alias: `alias@domain.com`

Can I configure aliaa@domain.com with the Pass of original ID?

```
Pass: originalpass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases don't have passwords - think of them as pointers.  When the mail server receives a message for alias@example it will internally look up that it is supposed to be delivered to original@example

The only account that exists is original@example and it is the only one that can be used to authenticate, retrieve mail once authenticated, etc

Comment: Ok, but can there be used any scrpit that explicitly tells system if configuration request from alias comes, authenticate it with original username? Just askin, in case there's a way.

Comment: With Open Source almost anything is possible, but it really depends on how your system is configured.  For example, my mail servers have a mysql back end so in theory I could write some queries, triggers, stored proceedures, etc. to handle that...

Comment: well fyi, we have email server at the backend of cpanel, if that helps you.